# Cannot find UI5 Visual Editor in Business Application Studio

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-business-application-studio

I used SAP Web IDE to create a list report based on SAPUI5. Now I have to work with SAP Business Application Studio.
On Web IDE, there was an option [*SAPUI5 Visual Editor*](https://help.sap.com/viewer/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/latest/en-US/72a0be71a48f49e086e1069785715711.html) which is useful to configure design and option for Fiori Elements based apps such as the List Report.

On Business Application Studio, I checked for the option but when I launch it, no reaction.

Does anyone know how I can do it?

I can't find any documentation on Business Application Studio in the web.

Comment: According to the doc, the _Visual Editor_ is still available in SAP BAS. Follow the documentation topic at https://help.sap.com/viewer/584e0bcbfd4a4aff91c815cefa0bce2d/latest/en-US/ada9567b767941aba8d49fdb4fdedea7.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is available in BAS.

To adapt the UI of standard delivered or existing Fiori app you must

1. Create SAPUI5 Adaptation Project
2. Add the Fiori app you want to adapt and generate the project
3. Select the **manifest.appdescr_variant** file in the webapp folder of your project
4. On right click you can access SAPUI5 Visual Editor

[image]

Check this [detailed guide](https://help.sap.com/viewer/584e0bcbfd4a4aff91c815cefa0bce2d/Cloud/en-US/2644b855e6324afb8d9c029e3cc0d897.html)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on view file and do open with.

[image: openwith]

After that select Layout Editor

[image: edit]

In addition if you facing any issue loading the layout editor tool then do check out [link](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13468531/business-application-studio-cant-get-layout-editor.html)

Check the reply about adding the extension to your workspace.